# クロスドメインのCookie発行

Tags: http, browser

### サイトAからサイトBに対するドメインをまたぐCookieを発行することはできますか？

サイトAのHTTPレスポンスが

```
Set-Cookie: name1=value1; サイトB; path=/
```

を返した場合、ブラウザでサイトBに遷移した際に、Cookieは送信されるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Set-Cookie: name1=value1; domain=サイトB; path=/
```

の誤記でしょうか？ Webブラウザはセキュリティ上の理由から、送信元以外のドメイン向けのCookieは受け取らないです。[RFC 6265 の 4.1.2.3.  The Domain Attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3)にも

> The user agent will reject cookies unless the Domain attribute specifies a scope for the cookie that would include the origin server.

と記されています。

ですので、送信するかどうかで言えばWebサーバー次第ではありますが、送信する意議がないです。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、誤記がありました。こちらの質問意図は、訂正して頂いた内容通りです。

Comment: ブラウザが送信元ではないドメインのCookieを受理しないということですね。ご返答ありがとうございました。